# Missing file systems features in relational model

Tags: database, filesystems, relational-database, relational-model

As I have searched over internet, I found many links which explained what are the differences of relational databases and (flat) file system and look at this topic from different aspects and points of view, like the following resources:

- [File System vs Databases](https://www.druva.com/blog/file-systems-vs-databases/): it describes the missing relational model features in file system but it doesn't mention the vice-versa features.
- [second link](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/difference-flat-file-relational-database)

As I mentioned above, my question is what are the missing file system features in relational model? in other words, what concepts of file systems like `pointers` (which is discussed about it here) are ignored to implement in relational model?

Comment: You seem to mean "file systems" or "collections of just files", not "system files". This is too vague. "FIle system" means too many things for too many purposes. Neither DBMSs (relational or not) nor relational databases are intended for what file systems do. You might mean non-relational DBMSs rather than file systems. You need to give *your own clear description of the categories of things you are talking about, not just use two words for each*. Don't just give a link. PS The point of the relational model is that DBMSs don't *need* (non-superkey) pointers & they only complicate things.

Comment: Read about file systems, DBMSs & "data models" (especially relational vs not) in the introductory chapters & chapter sections of some published academic textbooks on information modeling & database management. Dozens are free online in pdf. PS Once your question is clear it's going to be a faq.